# CodeIgniter .htaccess rewrite paths

Tags: php, angularjs, .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite

I'm using codeIgniter for my home project running an angularJS (yeoman) app as frontend.
CI already configured for HMVC structure and works fine.

My main problem is to rewrite some directories to the actual location based on an environment variable.

Here's my htaccess rules I have tried [(and here's the whole .htaccess)](http://pastebin.com/ebr3s1sq):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^movieapp.ds$
RewriteRule (.*) $1 [E=ENVIRONMENT:development]

#Redirects frontend app requests
RewriteCond %{ENV:ENVIRONMENT} ^development$
RewriteRule ^scripts/(.*)$ app/scripts/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^styles/(.*)$ app/styles/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^images/(.*)$ app/images/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^views/(.*)$ app/views/$1 [L]


RewriteCond %{ENV:ENVIRONMENT} ^production$
RewriteRule ^scripts/(.*)$ dist/scripts/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^styles/(.*)$ dist/styles/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^images/(.*)$ dist/images/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^views/(.*)$ dist/views/$1 [L]
```

**Folder structure**

- /application
- /app - angularJS app in development

  - /scripts
  - /styles
  - ...
- /system
- /dist

  - /scripts
  - /styles
  - ...

And I'd like to redirect the example.com/scripts/* requests - based on the environment variable - to the app/scripts or dist/scripts.

As you see I'm not an .htaccess expert so please while you post an answer keep it difficult just like a monkey could interpret it.

Thanks in advance

Comment: why aren't you just setting the path as constant or variable inside the app?

Comment: Because I'm loading the index.html view from CI controller. As I wrote I'm using yeoman generator ( generator-angular ) which has an own structure, and I have to keep it untouched.

Answer (score 0):

I can't talk about the whole .htaccess, and the functionality you want to obtain, but these RewriteRule(s) don't do what you expect, because of the flag [L]. It means "last". The first "last" flag met, stops the rewriting process, no other rule is read. In this case you may just delete the flags. More about the flags in this [apache doc page](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html). Roll the page all the way down, to find it.